# Python 3.8 TLSv1.3 socket close result in ConnectionResetError or ConnectionAbortedError

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, ssl

Client side:

```
data = b'\xff' * 1000000
ssock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0)
#context is created by ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH)
ssock = context.wrap_socket(ssock, server_hostname='xd1337sv')
ssock.connect((SERVERADDR, SERVERPORT))
ssock.sendall(data)
#time.sleep(3)
ssock.close()
```

If I just use regular non-SSL socket, everything works correctly with the server receiving exact amount of data. If I use TLS socket, the behavior then depends on the version.

If I run either the server or client on Python 3.6 and therefore the TLSv1.2 will be used, there's no problem.
Problem arises only when TLSv1.3 is used and depends on the size of `data` and how soon client `ssocket.close()` line is executed.

If I put a right amount of `time.sleep` before `ssocket.close()` depending on the size of data, then I get no error. Otherwise, the server will get `ConnectionResetError [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host` and receive only part of the data, or throw `ConnectionAbortedError [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine` and receive no data.

I'm testing both the server and client on my local machine with local address `192.168.1.2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is caused by TLS 1.3 sending a session ticket after the TLS handshake while with previous TLS versions the session ticket is send inside the TLS handshake. Thus, with TLS 1.3 data from the server (the session ticket) will arrive after the `ssock.connect(...)` is done. Since your application does not read any data after the `connect` it closes the socket while unread data are still inside the socket buffer of the underlying TCP socket. This will cause RST send to the server and cause there the connection reset error.

This is a known problems with applications which never attempt to read from the server. If the application would expect a response from the server and use `recv` to get it this would implicitly also read the session ticket.

To fix this situation when you don't expect the server to return any application data do a proper SSL shutdown of the socket before closing it. Since this will read the servers SSL shutdown message it will also implicitly read the session ticket send before by the server.

```
try:
    ssock = ssock.unwrap()
except:
    True
ssock.close()
```

For more information see also [this issue](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/7948) and [this documentation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/TLS1.3#Sessions).

Comment: This is surely a bug in Python? I doubt a Java client would do that.

Comment: @user207421: Kind of a bug in Python and kind of not. For example Perl IO::Socket::SSL tries a proper SSL shutdown by default and thus is not affected by the problem which is triggered by Python doing only a  plain close but no SSL shutdown by default. Java might do a SSL shutdown too, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar problem when the application was running through gunicorn with certificates. The jsondecodeerror problem randomly came to the client, i.e. the response was empty. The only thing that TLS 1.2 was used.

The solution was simple, I deployed the application on uwsgi and the problem went away